# Carga de archivo local a Firebase Storage

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-storage

**Contexto:**
Necesito realizar una carga de archivos a `Firebase Storage`, mediante una ruta local, por ejemplo "C:\temp\Archivo1.pdf"

**Contexto actualizado (2020-07-09)**
No me preocupa la ruta real de los archivos referente a otros usuarios, por que el único que subirá los archivos a **FireBase** seré yo, tengo la ruta de todos los archivos que se van a ir subiendo, pero para evitar que todos los nuevos archivos que se van generando estarlos subiendo de manera manual, es decir, con el input file, simplemente quiero mandar la ruta y que se suban en automático sin que nadie los seleccione con un input file.

**Resumen del problema:**
Estoy intentando realizar una carga de archivos a Firebase Storage pasándole una ruta local, ya tengo creada mi aplicación en Firebase y el repositorio listo, incluso ya logré subir un PDF mediante un `input file`, pero ahora lo que necesito es hacer una carga de un archivo pasándole una ruta local al método `PUT` del Storage.

**Lo que he intentando:**
Como comenté arriba ya logré subir un archivo, pero utilizando un input tipo file, ahora lo que necesito es subir el archivo proporcionando a través de una variable `String` la ruta del archivo.

**El código que sube el archivo es el siguiente:**

```js
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.2.0/firebase-app.js"></script>

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.2.0/firebase-storage.js"></script>

<script>
    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    var firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "mi_apiKey",
        authDomain: "mi_authDomain",
        databaseURL: "mi_databaseURL",
        projectId: "mi_projectId",
        storageBucket: "mi_storageBucket",
        messagingSenderId: "mi_messagingSenderId",
        appId: "mi_appId"
    };

    // Initialize Firebase
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

    // File or Blob named mountains.jpg
    //var file = 'file:///C:/Users/juan/Downloads/DocumentoPrueba.pdf'
    var file = 'C:\Users\juan\Downloads\DocumentoPrueba.pdf'

    var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();

    // Create the file metadata
    var metadata = {
        contentType: 'application/pdf'
    };

    storageRef.child('images/Prueba.pdf').putString(file).then(function (snapshot) {
        console.log('Uploaded a raw string!');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Bueno, decir que la ruta `REAL` de un archivo no se puede conseguir por medio de un `input file`, se que actualmente ya no usas el input file, pero definitivamente lo necesitaras, porque tu no sabes como esta constituido las rutas, las carpetas o incluso el `SO` del usuario, aquello que estas haciendo es hardcodear una ruta y solo funcionara en tu caso, o posiblemente en casos donde el usuario este usando windows y tenga exactamente la misma ruta con el mismo nombre y extension de archivo, lo cual es practicamente imposible (muy improbable).

Comment: En su lugar te recomiendo vuelvas a usar el `input file`, puesto que este te devuelve un `FileList`, que si no estoy mal tu a firebase puedes subir directamente un archivo haciendo uso de `Blobs` o de `Files`, por lo que es sumamente conveniente el input file en este caso, ya que puedes iterar el `FileList` e ir subiendo los archivos sin ningun problema y sin tener que preocuparte por cosas como el `SO` de la persona o la ruta de donde proviene el archivo.

Comment: El caso que propones parece mas bien un caso de posibilidades para tener en cuenta o un ejercicio, pero no un caso que usarias en la vida real, es decir, javascript no permite obtener la ruta real de un archivo por razones de seguridad, por lo que, lo que intentas es solo posible porque tu te sabes la ruta a la que apunta el archivo y el `SO` que estas usando, en un caso real tu no tienes acceso a la ruta real, y aunque la tuvieras `firebase` no usa la ruta si no los datos de esta. firebase no podria obtener la data con esa ruta.

Comment: Gracias por darme tus comentarios @Riven :)
En realidad no me preocupa la ruta real de los archivos referente a otros usuarios, por que el único que subirá los archivos a **FireBase**, yo tengo la ruta de todos los archivos que se van a ir subiendo, pero para evitar que todos los nuevos archivos que se van generando estarlos subiendo de manera manual, es decir, con el input file, simplemente quiero mandar la ruta y que se suban en automático sin que nadie los seleccione con un input file.

Comment: Concuerdo con lo que dice @Riven, en un caso de la vida real este tipo de comportamiento no sería útil para el usuario final, ya que desconoce la ruta absoluta de los archivos, adicional a ello JavaScript tampoco podrá acceder a este tipo de rutas desde un input de texto, usar un `input tipo file` es la forma más útil y recomendada para este tipo de tareas.

Comment: Si no te preocupa la ruta,  no crees entonces que es mas facil usar un input file para que se suban tus archivos en vez de ir coleccionando rutas que solo tu te sabes en javascript?, es decir,  si se trata de acortar lo que deseas hacer seria mucho mas rapido usar el input file, que estar copido y pegando rutas para que posteriormente se manden los archivos a firebase,  pero de todas formas,  como ya he dicho en un anterior comentario Firebase NO PUEDE usar una ruta local tuya para subir el archivo,  porque firebase NO tiene acceso a los archivos de tu computadora mediante su ruta.

Comment: Conclusion: no puedes subir archivos de esa manera,  porque firebase usa blobs o Files para subir la informacion,  mas NO rutas,  firebase no solo no estaria autorizado para obtener informacion de un archivo haciendo uso de una ruta local,  si no que ademas no puedes darle acceso y firebase rechazaria el hacer esto,  ya que se consideraria algo excesivamente inseguro,  tendrias que dar muchos permisos y exponerte ante todos en la red para que firebase pueda acceder a un archivo de tu PC mediante su ruta directa.

Comment: Por este motivo se encuentra el input file, que te devuelve una copia ya transformada a un Blob o un File del archivo en cuestion, para poder que esta pueda ser subida luego a firebase de manera directa y segura, pues despues de todo el input file nunca te mostrara ni dara acceso a las rutas del pc de manera directa. y las copias no las almacenaria el pc si no el navegador en una sandbox, (tecnicamente firebase tendria acceso a archivos en una sandbox del navegador,  pero no a los originales). lo cual es mucho mas seguro.

Comment: Gracias @Riven por tus comentarios :D pues creo que intentare alguna otra cosa, cerrare el tema, muchas gracias a todos. Saludos.